# Metal part of the pedal is coming off

Tags: pedals

I noticed that screws connecting the metal part of the pedal are loose (I don't know the proper name for the metal part). I would like to screw them in but there's a piece of plastic that is in the way. How should I go about this (I don't want to yank the plastic part off the pedal). Here the picture:
[image]

Comment: The piece of plastic should contain a reflector. If it's already been broken, it doesn't have any function and can as well be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you will have to remove the reflector to get to the screws and there doesn't seem to be a non-destructive way. The mounts for the reflectors look like they are designed as one-way plugs. You could drill holes into the reflector to get to the screws without removing the reflector - which would be difficult to put back on. Even if you get this screwed back together, this is not going to last: the plastic is too weak to withstand the forces exercised from the metal plate when you stand on it.

I'm not sure this is worth the trouble. These are cheap pedals for which you can buy replacements on Ebay for under $€£ 10 from China including shipping.

Comment: I actually managed to remove the reflectors in a way that didn't damage them because it turns out the reflectors are attached to the metal via sort of "cushioned" plastic screw-like structure. So I tightened the screws and popped the reflectors back.

Comment: @yos great work!  Do expect the screw will pop out again over time.  You should consider squirting something like threadlocker (ie loctite) or cyanoacrylate (superglue) in to help.  Long term, once the plastic is deformed it's never going to hold as well.

Comment: @yos Christian is right - these are cheap pedals.  Look out for some all-metal ones as a replacement.  Obviously you're strong and generating a decent amount of power through your legs, more than the pedal can cope with!